# Why does 'US keyboard' keep adding itself to keyboard layout list?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I use Windows 10. I have two keyboard layouts configured: 'United Kingdom' and 'United Kingdom - Colemak'.

However sometimes (often after playing fullscreen games) 'US keyboard' will add itself to the list (first screenshot). How can I stop that?

[image]

**Edit**: 'English (United Kingdom)' which is the only language configured. US keyboard is not listed.

[image]

[image]

---

This seems to be a common problem:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3rx32w/keyboard_us_keeps_adding_itself_as_an_input/
2. [image]

Comment: What language packs do you have installed.  What build of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: @Ramhound only 'English (United Kingdom)' with those two keyboard layouts. Added screenshots above. Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.10586 build 10586

Comment: Try in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language` to reset the value of `InstallLanguage` from `0409` (English US) to `0809` (English UK) and reboot. These values are [listed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: It _is_ possible that the PC games require the US variant to be active in order to receive the correct charcodes..

Answer (score 3):

Try in registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language`
to reset the value of `InstallLanguage` from 0409 (English US) to 0809 (English UK) and reboot.

These language constants are documented in the Microsoft article
[Locale IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: It turns out InstallLanguage was already set to English UK

Comment: It might be that some product you are using adds the language for you. You will have to track it down.

Comment: Interesting. My "Default" key in that reg location was 0809, but "InstallLanguage" was 0409. That could well be the cause.